# Spring Cloud Config - How do we see this being used?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have been playing with [Spring Cloud Config](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/) and like many of the ideas I see there.  I would like to better understand how its creators intended on it being used though.

Lets say that I have several services that support a larger API.  Because these services are independent from each other, their source is managed in separate repositories.  This allows us to version them and deploy them separately from one another.  Today, their properties are managed individually.

I like the idea of having a single config server provide all of the configuration information for the individual applications/services that support this larger API.  Looking at the default implementation of EnvironmentRepository (which is GIT based), I would have to have a single repository with all of my application config files in it.  Because they all live within the same repository, they would all be managed/versioned together in a single place.

How do I make both models work with each other?  Would it be better to have a repository per application instead of one for all applications?  What are your thoughts?

-Joshua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might just be a detail of the implementation of the `EnvironmentRepository`. See [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/58) for some discussion on how and when that might happen.